# Filtering SQL tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set up an sms appointment reminder for client appointments. I use the cms [opemEMR](http://open-emr.org/). But there do not seem to be a appointment reminder function installed, and no extentions for that function. So I thought it will be possible to do that by filtering out the appointment from SQLi using PHP, and then set up a cron job.

I am new to php and mySQL, and I have been re-thinking how to do it so many times, that by head spins, so I hope some one can show me the right direction.

Here is how I think it can be done:

First I need to go to the calendar table that holds all the calendar events(1), and find the client appointments(2). Then I need to filter the appointments, that scheduled between 24 - 25 hours in advanced(3) (I will then tell the cron job to run every hour).

Then I will need to grab the client id(4) and the time of the appointment.
[image]

I will now have client ids on all client, I need to send reminders to.

Second I need to go to the patient data table(5), to grab the phone number(6) from the client ids(7) I just extracted.
[image]

I guess, I can then put this data in to another table, from where I can fetch it when running my sms-reminder.

This is a way, I believe would work, but I am no sure how to do it. Hope some one can show me.

Hope it makes sense and that the images help.

Reg.
Lars

Comment: It sounds like you're just looking for a SQL tutorial.  A `SELECT` statement with a combination of `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses would be what you want.

Comment: Hi David. Thank you for replying. Ill have a look into it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this query:

```
SELECT e.pc_pid, e.pc_eventDate, e.pc_startTime,p.phone_cell FROM opememr_postcalendar_events e
LEFT JOIN patient_data p ON p.id = e.pc_pid
WHERE e.pc_Title = 'Office Visit' AND e.pc_eventDate BETWEEN DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) ) AND DATE ( NOW() ) 
ORDER BY e.pc_eventDate, e.pc_startTime;
```